# sequences and series concerning e.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So i am supposed to prove

$$(1+\frac{1}{1})^1(1+\frac{1}{2})^2(1+\frac{1}{3})^3....(1+\frac{1}{x-1})^{x-1}=\frac{x^x}{x!}$$ and

$$(1+\frac{1}{1})^2(1+\frac{1}{2})^3(1+\frac{1}{3})^4....(1+\frac{1}{x-1})^{x}=\frac{x^x}{(x-1)!}$$

For the first part where i cheated a bit i have:

$\frac{a_{x+1}}{a_x}=(\frac{(x+1)}{(x)})^x=(1+\frac{1}{x})^x$ which has the limit $e$. And since $\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$, the first equation holds. (I skipped over the algebra, i double checked there no mistake there)

But i dont know how to do the second part if someone could give me a hint,.

Also, the exercise had me prove that $(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x+1}$ was monotonically increasing which i did...I suppose its related to this question...

Comment: The first one is wrong. You get $x^{x-1}$ in the numerator on RHS. Also, this formula follows by simple algebra and there is no need for differentiation etc.

Comment: sorry my scratch paper was messy

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy. For $x\in \Bbb N$ we have $x^x/x!= ( x^{x-1}\cdot x)/ ((x-1)!\cdot x)=x^{x-1}/(x-1)!$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet The first formula is false when $x=3$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy . When $x=3$ we have $(1+1/1)^1\cdot (1+1/(3-1))^{3-1}=2\cdot (3/2)^2=9/2$ and we have $3^3/3!=27/6=9/2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(1+\frac{1}{1})^2(1+\frac{1}{2})^3(1+\frac{1}{3})^4....(1+\frac{1}{x-1})^{x}=\frac {2^{2}} {1^{2}}\frac {3^{3}} {2^{3}}...\frac {x^{x}} {(x-1)^{x}}=\frac{x^x}{(x-1)!}$$ after obvious cancellations.

Comment: Thanks,,,but i dont think i am supposed to do it this way....I am supposed to use properties of e and monotonic sequences....

Comment: The equation is for  a fixed $x$ and there are no infinite sequences or series. It makes no sense to use monotonic sequences and limits. This is a question in High school pre-Caculus algebra. @JerryCohen

Comment: You are writing $x!$ and $(x-1)!$ Is $x$ supposed to be a positive integer or a real number? Is $x!$ supposed to be $\Gamma (x+1)$?  @JerryCohen

Comment: Mabye im overthinking this....maybe it was supposed to be an easy one......And yeah x is supposed to be a poisitive integer